# Set font size on parameter text on .Rdlc

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer, rdlc

I have a problem with this.

I have a `rdlc` report in `ASP.NET`.
I have a parameter text, that is showed.

I have no problem with that - the problem is the size of the text in that parameter.
I have a textbox, and the value showed is

```
"Reporte de Señas " + Parameters!NombreTipoReporte.Value
```

The text is right, but the report show it in normal size (9 pt).
I change the format in textbox to 24pt, but its not effective - still seeing it at 9 pt.

```
<Textbox Name="NombreTipoReporte">
          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
          <CanShrink>true</CanShrink>
          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
          <Paragraphs>
            <Paragraph>
              <TextRuns>
                <TextRun>
                  <Value>= "Reporte de Señas " + Parameters!NombreTipoReporte.Value</Value>
                  <Style>
                    <FontSize>24pt</FontSize>
                  </Style>
                </TextRun>
              </TextRuns>
              <Style />
            </Paragraph>
          </Paragraphs>
          <rd:DefaultName>NombreTipoReporte</rd:DefaultName>
          <Top>0.7155cm</Top>
          <Left>0.28258cm</Left>
          <Height>1.64811cm</Height>
          <Width>14.59083cm</Width>
          <ZIndex>3</ZIndex>
          <Style>
            <FontSize>24pt</FontSize>
            <Border>
              <Style>None</Style>
            </Border>
            <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
            <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
            <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
            <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
          </Style>
        </Textbox>
```

Why is showed in normal size? In design view I can see 24 pt font size. And I've set this size from design view, and also not working.

When I open the web, I see the text in 9pt.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to modify the properties of the **parameter placeholder** and not the **properties of the text box**?

Just click on the parameter placeholder (the one with the `[@parameterName]`), right click on it, properties, on the left select Font and then change the size.

Comment: In my project I've done in the easiest way I know: select all the words in the textbox and than changed the size/bold form the toolbar

Comment: The only difference I see from your xml is that your parameter is containing a static string. Have you try to put it outside the parameter?